# Splitting a file based on every X number of regex pattern matches

Tags: bash

This question is similar to [Splitting text files based on a regular expression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15662/splitting-text-files-based-on-a-regular-expression), but not quite the same. My problem is that I don't want to split it into a specific number of files, but I actually want to split it based on the number of matches. For example: I have a 457 MB file and trying to split it down into much smaller files. Here's what's currently working:

```
csplit -z Scan.nessus /\<ReportHost/ '{*}'
```

However, this creates about 61.5k files for me as I have a *ton* of these `<ReportHost` entries in this 457MB file. Ultimately, I'd like to break this down by every 50 entries rather than every single entry.

Is there a way to modify this to accomplish that? I tried doing this in Ruby to some extent, but it seems to max out the VM's memory trying to parse through the file with Nokogiri.

Comment: You could roll your own with awk - see [Split file into n files using csplit (or similar tool)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557632/split-file-into-n-files-using-csplit-or-similar-tool)

Comment: "this creates about 61.5k for me" – Do you mean "about 61.5k new files"? If the new files are already there, concatenating in bunches of 50 may be easier than processing the original file anew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusing the `awk`-approach

```
BEGIN{outfile="part_0" ; j=-1}
/\<ReportHost/ {j++}
j==50 {outfile="part_"++i ; j=0}
{print > outfile}
```

Run as

```
awk -f split.awk Scan.nessus
```

Problem of not removing the old file while processing remains.

For zero-padded outfiles, you may use

```
outfile="part_"sprintf("%04d",i++)
```

and "part_0000" in the BEGIN block. Then hope not to have more than 10,000 files. Or check the number of files you expect beforehand.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately this provides the following error: `awk: split.awk: line 3: syntax error at or near 1`. Tried fixing this myself but not familiar enough with awk to this extent.

Comment: @user3447014 should have been `++i` ... `i` is the output file index that is to be increased.